# JPQL time interval

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, date, subtraction

What I'm trying to do is quite simple in sql but I can't get it to work with JPQL.

The problem is that my date formats don't match each other. In my database the date is stored like `2011-12-04 18:19:00`

What I've tried is:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -GlobalConfig.heartbeatInterval);
    Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select uo from UserOnline uo where lastActive < " + cal.getTime());
```

But this is giving me this error: `IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Dec near line 1, column 60 [select uo from models.UserOnline uo where lastActive < Sun Dec 04 19:22:17 CET 2011]`

Any ideas?

Comment: In your database, the date is not stored like 2011-12-04 18:19:00. It's stored in binary form, and displayed by your database browsing tool to 2011-12-04 18:19:00 to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do "QueryText" + cal.getTime(), you are telling Java to convert cal.getTime() to a String and append it to the query text.  You can see it clearly in the exception, it provided the query it attempted...

```
select uo from models.UserOnline uo where lastActive < Sun Dec 04 19:22:17 CET 2011
```

See? 'Sun Dec 04 19:22:17 CET 2011' is just a bunch of text here, and Hibernate's query engine has no idea how to parse it.

I would change your query slightly to take an argument, which is the time...

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select uo from UserOnline uo where lastActive < :lastActive");
query.setParameter("lastActive", cal.getTime());
```

**EDIT**: Took advice from JB Nizet and changed this from numbered to named parameters.

Comment: +1: better yet, use a named parameter : "where lastActive < :limit" and use setParameter("limit", cal.getTime()).